# How do I Embeded an Chart in a Specific Cell in a table in MS Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to embeded a chart in a specific cell in a table. The only way I have been able to get it to work is using selection.cut and paste. This doesn't work after second and third run. This what I have so far:

```
   Dim data1 As Variant
data1 = InputBox("What was the Moving Water damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")

Dim data2 As Variant
data2 = InputBox("What was the Settlement damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")

Dim data3 As Variant
data3 = InputBox("What was the Pre-Exisiting damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")


Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
i = i + 1

' Create table
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=2
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 2).Split NumColumns:=3
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Location:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Quantity (Measurable Area):"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Description:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Analysis:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Cause(s) of Damage:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = "Recommended Repairs:"

With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With

Dim small As Boolean
small = False
Dim twoSeries As Boolean
twoSeries = False
Dim pieChart As Boolean
pieChart = True

Dim salesChart As Chart
Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet


With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With

With ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 2).Range
    ActiveDocument.Range(.Start, .Start).Select
End With

' Add in a new chart
Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chartWorkSheet = salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)

' Resize the chart area
chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.Range("A1:B4")

' Rename Series 1 as Sales
chartWorkSheet.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = "Damage"

' Add data to the chart
chartWorkSheet.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Moving Water"
chartWorkSheet.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "Settlement"
chartWorkSheet.Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "Pre-Exisiting"
chartWorkSheet.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = data1
chartWorkSheet.Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = data2
chartWorkSheet.Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = data3


' Quit Excel, since we no longer need it
salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit

' Put a box around the legend
salesChart.Legend.Format.Line.Visible = msoCTrue

' Fill the background with theme color accent 1
With salesChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Solid
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent1
End With

' Add a title and format it
salesChart.HasTitle = True
With salesChart.ChartTitle
    .Characters.Font.Italic = True
    .Characters.Font.Size = 18
    .Characters.Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 100)
    .Text = "Damage"
End With


If small Then
' Size and move the chart
With salesChart.Parent
    .Left = 100
    .Width = 300
    .Height = 150
End With
End If

If pieChart Then
' Set chart type
    salesChart.ChartType = xl3DPie
End If
```

Comment: it's working for me quite good (macro places your charts in cell(1,1) of each new table)... where and which type of error you have...

Comment: how do I get it to place it in cell (4,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place your chart within cell(4,2) you need to select Range within this cell. Therefore add this code within your code before you add chart to your document:

```
'....your code here

'<-- new code --
    'select destination cell
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 2).Range
        ActiveDocument.Range(.Start, .Start).Select
    End With
'-- new code -->

'your code...
' Add in a new chart
Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chartWorkSheet = salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)
```

Comment: I'm using word 2007 and it is still placing it in cell (1,1). When I run the macro a second time. The graph goes in the first table and not the second table.

http://i44.tinypic.com/343tf7s.jpg

Comment: in the same document, you run it one by one without any additional changes in the document??

Comment: the only changes I make is I press enter to place the cursor on a new line.

Comment: I have recognised that problem but pressing enter (at the end of document?!) should solve it. I'm running Word 2010 and there is nothing like your problem. What is going wrong could have inclination in this lines `i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count | 
i = i + 1`. Check them with debugging options if I returns what is expected... Moreover, are you sure you have placed my answer in right place??

Comment: assuming that your code is complete `Sub procedure` it works fine for me... What I've added to avoid additional manual works (enter typing) are two lines of code just before end of the `Sub`: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Endofdoc").Select | 
Selection.TypeParagraph`

Comment: I found the issue. This code works on only Word 2010 with the library Excel 14.0 and 12.0 installed. It does not work in Word 2007 with only Excel 12.0 libary or in Word 2010 with only the Excel 14.0 library installed. Is their a way to make it more compatible with different versions of MS Word?

Comment: It is really strange what you have found out. It is also strange that we operate with very simple instructions. I could suggest only manual debugging and checking different options with word range navigation  before inserting table... or you could ask another question here in SO regarding this particular problem. Possibly someone has encounter something similar and knows the solution. I'll look forward to seeing the answer..